# How do I check and set the URL and port number for JBoss 5?

Tags: jboss

How do I check and set the URL and port number for JBoss 5? I have a existing JBoss installation in a zip file that I am trying to use. How do I find out what URL and port number I need to type in my browser to access it when it's running? How would I go about modifying this setting to change the URL and port number?

I'm running this in windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by finding in the file /jboss.5.1.0.ga/server/default/jbossweb.sar/server.xml the HTTP connector was commented out so it was using the AJP connector. I enabled the HTTP connector and was able to connect to jboss using the standard `http://localhost:8080` address. I believe you can change the port number as well as the URL in this same area.